# How come jQuery '$(document).html(data)' doesn't refresh page

Tags: jquery

How come doesn't

```
    $('#submit').click(function(){
        $.post('PHP/script.php', $('#form').serialize(), function(data){
                $(document).html(data);
        });
    });
```

refresh the entire page when script.php in this case would return e.g.:

```
echo '<p>Some text</p>';
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
$(document).html(data);
```

by

```
$(document.body).html(data);
```

You can't replace the document without reloading it, only its content.

Comment: Naturally! Thanks so much! I'll click accept as soon as the system allows me to!

Comment: @PulkitMittal Are you sure ? `window.body` is undefined as far as I know.

Comment: @PulkitMittal OK. `$('body')` does work but it's slower as a search must occur. `$(document.body)` is the cleanest.

Comment: But I was thinking what if I wanted to import the <head> as well from the other file?

Comment: Why not simply post the form without ajax in this case ?

Comment: @dystroy not possible in this case due to... cosmetic reasons. Basically there is one set of checkboxes with different functions depending on what <div> is clicked.

Comment: @Matte I guessed it, I was answering to Pulkit.